# ActiveRecord: check whether association exists without loading it?

Tags: activerecord

Suppose I've got ActiveRecord models such that `User has_one :photo`. In the database, `photos` has a `t.binary` column which may hold a lot of data, so I don't want to `SELECT` that column unless I need to.

I want to do something like:

```
users.each do |user|
  image_tag(user_photo_path) if user.photo.present?
end
```

However, I don't want to call `user.photo.present?` because:

- Doing so loads the `photo` association, including `SELECT * from photos`
- Even if it could be made to only `SELECT id FROM photos` to check existence, it's still an N + 1 query.

What I really want is to load `users` with a single query which gives each one a property telling me whether it has an associated photo or not.

Answer (score 1):

With ActiveRecord 5, this works:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                     
  scope :with_photo_id, -> { 
     left_outer_joins(:photo).select(
       "users.*, photos.id AS photo_id"
     )
   }

 end
```

Then I can call `User.with_photo_id` and check `user.photo_id.present?`.

Prior to AR 5, the join would be uglier:

```
  joins(
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN photos ON photos.user_id = users.id"
  )
```